# How to link to files and change base url in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Hello I've been running into a few issues with CI lately. When I want to link a css file to pretty much anything, I need to put it directly into the root folder. If I move the file somewhere further in the hierarchy it won't load it. Here's an example of when I am trying to link this `core_css.css`. It loads the one in the `htdocs` folder, but not the one in the `css` folder.

[image: folder structure]

Works:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>core_css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Does NOT work:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/OBS/css/core_css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I've tried putting the css filed in all the other subfolders and linking those, but it only loads the one in the root.

My second problem is that every time I try to test a controller, I need to access it through `index.php` like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/index.php/test_controller
```

Is there a way to get rid of the need to put the `index.php` in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second question: put the following in an .htaccess file inside your CodeIgniter root folder (`htdocs` in your case):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to set `$config['index_page']` to an empty string, and also set `$config['base_url']` accordingly (these two options are inside `/application/config/config.php`)

For the first question: try to make a folder called `assets`, or something similar and put it in the root of the site (again inside `htdocs`). Move your css file there, and try to access it by visiting `http://localhost:8888/assets/core_css.css`.

Also, in case you are using Linux box, make sure the folders you want to access have read permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. All works :) I knew it was just something in the configs :). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**For your first problem:**

Add .htaccess file in your root web directory and write allow from all it means, in this folder your all files and all folder will not give error Access forbidden! use it like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

N.B:
I usually put all my files like that into an "assets" folder in the application root, and then I make sure to use an [Asset_Helper](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Asset-Helper) to point to those files for me. This is what CodeIgniter suggests.

**For your second problem:**
If you are using Apache place a .htaccess file in your root web directory containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

for better understand you can see codeigniter URL section through this link
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/urls.html

and another one is http://snipplr.com/view/5966/codeigniter-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you so much. I used what the first reply said, but I can see yours is the same, I hope you won't mind I accepted the first one? I guys even answers 3 mins away from each other. And thank you for the links, already reading them.